# How to make an eager loading and left join?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I have two tables in my database in a 1:N relation and I would like to do a left join query with eager loading.

My tables are:

- `Videos` (`IDVIdeo, Name...` )
- `Versions` (`IDVersion, IDVideo, Name, Avaliable...`)

Well, in a video I can have many versions (DVD, Blu-Ray... etc) and a version only can belong to a video.

I would like to get all the videos which I have at least one available version (perhaps some version are in possession of one friend).

I would like to know if I have at least one version that I can see because I have this version. Also I would like that in the collection of the Versions in the Videos entity I would like to have all the versions that I have (no matter if one version is available or not, I would like to know which is available and which no).

How can I do this query? I would like to use eager loading to do only one query to the database. I would prefer to do that query with raw SQL, but raw SQL does not allow to use eager loading.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create [navigation property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) in Video class which will hold versions (if you don't have it generated):

```
public class Video
{
   public Video
   {
       Versions = new HashSet<Version>();
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

Then when loading videos do [eager loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) of versions:

```
var query = db.Videos.Include(v => v.Versions);
```